# How to use DevOps nuget package in solution pulled from DevOps

Tags: c#, macos, azure-devops, nuget

I am verified in DevOps using an ssh key (at least for git)

So I pulled a solution from `mycompany@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:v3/mycompany/thing/thing`, and tried to build it using `dotnet build`, but get the error

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.402/NuGet.targets(128,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://mycompany.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/SomeProject/nuget/v3/index.json.
> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.402/NuGet.targets(128,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

How can I get around this (I assume by authenticating with the sources server) and build the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install [Azure Artifacts Credential Provider](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider) and once you do it run `dotnet restore --interactive` and then you will be prompted to login to a page like below:

[image]